# ASP MVC Controller And Static Variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have list of connection strings in web.config.
And user has his "active" connection string from this list in cookie.
This cookie can be chaged only at startup of app.
So, in each request to controller i have to write:

```
Request.Cookies["activeServer"].Value
```

And pass it to repository.
I think this is bad code, how can i do it better.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        try
        {
            var m = new HomeRepository(Request.Cookies["activeServer"].Value);
            m.Tree = m.GetObjectsTree();
            return View(m);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("error", ex);
        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Lists()
    {
        try
        {
            var m = new HomeRepository(Request.Cookies["activeServer"].Value);
            return View(m.GetListsModel());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("error",ex);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Let me get this straight. The user's active connection string is chosen by an unencrypted and unchecked-to-be-valid value stored in a client cookie? So all he has to do is modify the cookie and he can change which server he connects to? That isn't just *bad*, if true that's *hideous*.

Comment: user selects KEY of the connection string, and he does have access to all this connection strings. I have 10 same databases, and this is one app for all of them in one.

Comment: In that case, it's not as bad as I was worried about--if the user has access to all the connection strings, then okay. Sorry to have freaked out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use dependency injection in this case

Define function:

```
public string GetConnectionString()
{
    //You should also check that cookie is no t null and value is not null...
    return Request.Cookies["activeServer"].Value;
}
```

Your controller constructor should get a repository as an argument:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IHomeRepository HomeRepo {get; private set;}
    public HomeController (IHomeRepository repo)
    { 
       this.HomeRepo = repo;
    }
}
```

Define repository interface

```
public interface IHomeRepository
{
}
```

Define implementation of IHomeRepository

```
public class HomeRepository : IHomeRepository
{
    public Func<string> _getConnectionString;

    private string _connectionString;

    public HomeRepository( Func<string> getConnectionString)
    {
       this._getConnectionString = getConnectionString
    }

    public string ConnectionString {
        get{

           if(!this._connectionString.IsNullOrEmpty())
              return this._connectionString;

           if(this._getConnectionString == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException();

           this._connectionString = this._getConnectionString();
           return  this._connectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

Use some dependency injection library to inject GetConnectionString function as a delegate to HomeRepository controller

If you decide to use [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/) library for example the injection will look like :

```
container.RegisterSingle(GetConnectionString);
container.Register<IHomeRepository, HomeRepository>();
```

By applying this pattern you won't have to manually create your repositories in every action, you would be able to inject fake/mock repository object for testing

Comment: I like it but don't agree with `ArgumentNullException` as used, since this is reserved for arguments supplied to parameters on the *current method call*. I recommend `InvalidOperationException` as this carries the correct meaning--it's invalid to get a connectionstring that is null when there is no injected method to call to get one.

Comment: Actually when i use similar pattern, i create custom exception that extends ApplicationException (IoCException / InjectionExcepton or something like that). ArgumentNullException added here to emphasize that getConnectionString function can not be null. I guess InvalidOperationException could be used here as well...

Answer (score 1):

Static variable for whole MVC application:

Create static class with static properties in it:

```
public static class Dictionaries
{
    //for example
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

Initialize it with values in global.asax Application_Start() method.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // other code
    new CommonDictionary().DictionariesInit();
}
```

Example of initializing class:
public class CommonDictionary
    {

```
public void DictionariesInit()
{
    Dictionaries.Statuses = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>(from s in new StatusDAO().GetStatuses()
     select new KeyValuePair<int, string>(s.StatusID, s.StatusName));    
}
```

Now you can access your static value from any part of code Controller, BLL, DAL.

Comment: Something about this just doesn't set right with me.

Comment: @ErikE that confuses you?

Comment: In order in to be available in Controller, BLL, DAL, this class has to be defined in separate assembly (maybe infrastructure) that is referenced by all other assemblies - just by defining it as static or initializing it on app start doesn't mean that it would be accessible from any part of the code ...

Comment: @Alex Art I have several working web applications where this approach is used. No referencing to any other assemblies needed. Very useful for rarely modified dictionaries without frequent queries to the database

Comment: Well if your UI, BLL, DAL defined in a single project it will work...
But it doesn't mean that it is the best way to structure your solution

Comment: @Alex Art. first you sad it wont work, now it isn't the best way. I understand that this is not the place where we should discuss it. Unjustified statements sound unfounded. Thx.

Comment: @aleha I didn't say it confuses me, I said it doesn't set right--it's setting off alarms bells that good software practices are being violated. A global multipurpose dictionary in which *anything* can be stored that happens to have connection strings sometimes and who-knows-what-all other times? It sounds like a weak point ripe for errors.

Comment: @ErikE all depends on the seriousness of the project.

Comment: In my software development I operate on the theory that in all projects, even the small ones, habits are set and mental patterns are formed. I try to write all projects according to best practices so that when I'm working on a "serious" project, I Haven't already painted myself into a corner with non-optimal choices, and doing the right thing just comes automatically without much thinking (because I practiced the *right* thinking over and over in the "less serious" projects). To me, all projects are serious because I'm training my brain.

Comment: @ErikE it is hard and has no point to discus thing like this here. Everyone got his own point of view.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to disagree. "Code smells" are real and are called that precisely because they're hard to nail down objectively. I've learned to trust my instinct when code makes me feel uneasy, as usually I find out later that there were solid software design principles supporting that feeling. My opinion as it stands may be worth less to some than others (or worthless, even, as the case may be) but it is still a useful data point for folks to see that some people on S.O. do not agree with this method.